# Center and horizontally align two divs, and then vertically align on smaller screen

Tags: html, css, center

I basically have two side by side lists and I want them to be centered within their container. I can't copy all the code surrounding the div because there are a million spaces before it since the HTML file is extremely large and convoluted. It doesn't copy in right with copy/paste.

[image]

```
<div style="padding-right:0px; padding-left:0px; overflow:auto; width: 100%; margin:0 auto; max-width:400px; display:inline-block;">
  <div style="float:left;">
    <ul>
      <li>On-demand tutoring</li>
      <li>Library systems</li>
      <li>Dedicated support teams</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div style="float:right;">
    <ul>
      <li>Counseling</li>
      <li>Technical support</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: BTW the second part you see (Get Career) is actually an image, so I cannot use that as reference for how to align things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep the list in one `ul` element and use `column-count: 2;` on it to split it into columns. The centering is done with `margin: 0 auto;` on the container. I erased th unnecessary `div` in between and moved the inline CSS to the external stylesheet.

And the use a media query to set `column-count` to `1`  for smaller screens:

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 400px;
}

.list1 {
  column-count: 2;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .list1 {
    column-count: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul class="list1">
    <li>On-demand tutoring</li>
    <li>Library systems</li>
    <li>Dedicated support teams</li>

    <li>Counseling</li>
    <li>Technical support</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you this seems to do what I want!!!    Do you know how I would make it so that once it's in a single column, the column does not align left, but aligns so that the text is in the middle of the screen?   Also, the items in the right column don't have the dots next to them using this technique. How do I get the dots back?

Comment: Add a smaller `max-width` setting for the container inside the media query

Answer (score 2):

```
<div style="padding-right:0px; padding-left:0px; overflow:auto; width: 100%; margin:0 auto; max-width:400px; display:inline-block;">
    <div style="float:left;text-align:center;">
        <ul>
            <li>On-demand tutoring</li>
            <li>Library systems</li>
            <li>Dedicated support teams</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div style="float:right;text-align:center;">
        <ul>
            <li>Counseling</li>
            <li>Technical support</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Change your current doe to this, this should suffice for what you need.